# Labels not displaying when rendering to image with pyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm using the simple example in the pyQGIS cookbook
http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html

I'm able to manipulate the features in my layer using Python, but the already configured labels are not rendered to the exported image.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import time
l = iface.activeLayer()

for a in l.getFeatures():
    attrs = {16: 1}
    l.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({a.id(): attrs})
    img = QImage(QSize(1280, 1024), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
    # set image's background color
    color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
    img.fill(color.rgb())
    # create painter
    p = QPainter()
    p.begin(img)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    render = QgsMapRenderer()

    palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    palyr.readFromLayer(l)
    lst = [l.id()]
    render.setLayerSet(lst)
    render.setLabelingEngine(QgsPalLabeling())
    # set extent
    rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
    rect.scale(1.1)
    render.setExtent(rect)
    render.setScale(1)

    render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
    render.render(p)
    p.end()
    # save image
    img.save("~/GIS/O/%s.jpg" % a['NAME_1'],"jpg")
    attrs = {16: 0}
    l.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({a.id(): attrs})
    time.sleep(1)
```